# twisted manhole: how to access servers in application?

Tags: python, twisted, telnet

I need to connect to my [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedCore) application at runtime and I am trying to get [twisted.manhole](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.manhole.html) to work for me to that end. I am on Mac OSX 10.6 with twisted 8.2 as installed by default.

The [sample server using twistd](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/telnet.html) works. There are DeprecationWarnings at startup about md5, sha and twisted.protocols.telnet, but the manhole server actually does what it is supposed to and I can access internals of my application:

```
host:client user$ telnet localhost 4040
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

twisted.manhole.telnet.ShellFactory
Twisted 8.2.0
username: admin
password: *****
>>> dir()
['_', '__builtins__', 'factory', 'service']
>>> factory
<twisted.manhole.telnet.ShellFactory instance at 0x101256440>
>>> service
<twisted.application.internet.TCPServer instance at 0x10124ff38>
>>> service.parent
<twisted.application.service.MultiService instance at 0x1014b0cf8>
>>>
```

Now I try to integrate this into my application:

```
# test_manhole.tac

from twisted.application.internet import TCPServer
from twisted.application.service  import Application, IServiceCollection
from twisted.manhole.telnet       import ShellFactory

shell_factory = ShellFactory()
shell_factory.username = 'admin'
shell_factory.password = 'admin'
shell_factory.namespace['some_value'] = 42
shell_tcp_server = TCPServer(4040, shell_factory)

application = Application('test')
serviceCollection = IServiceCollection(application)

shell_tcp_server.setServiceParent(serviceCollection)
```

Run the above code in a shell:

```
host:server user$ twistd -noy test_manhole.tac
(omitting the same DeprecationWarnings about md5, sha and twisted.protocols.telnet as earlier)
2011-08-24 16:52:13+1000 [-] Log opened.
2011-08-24 16:52:13+1000 [-] twistd 8.2.0 (/usr/bin/python2.6 2.6.1) starting up.
2011-08-24 16:52:13+1000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2011-08-24 16:52:13+1000 [-] twisted.manhole.telnet.ShellFactory starting on 4040
2011-08-24 16:52:13+1000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.manhole.telnet.ShellFactory instance at 0x1012cfdd0>
2011-08-24 16:52:13+1000 [-] start service:  <twisted.application.internet.TCPServer instance at 0x1012cff80>
```

In a second shell, run a telnet client:

```
host:client user$ telnet localhost 4040
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

twisted.manhole.telnet.ShellFactory
Twisted 8.2.0
username: admin
password: *****
>>> dir()
['_', '__builtins__', 'factory', 'service', 'some_value']
>>> factory
<twisted.manhole.telnet.ShellFactory instance at 0x1012cfdd0>
>>> service
>>> service == None
True
>>> service.parent
      ...
exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent'
>>> some_value
42
```

So it seems the service object is not usable to access application internals.

OK, since `twisted.protocols.telnet` anyway seems to have been superseded by `twisted.conch.telnet`, try using the newer module:

```
# test_manhole_2.tac

from twisted.application.service import Application, IServiceCollection
from twisted.conch.manhole_tap   import makeService

options = \
{
    # for some reason, these must
    # all exist, even if None
    'namespace'  : None,
    'passwd'     : 'users.txt',
    'sshPort'    : None,
    'telnetPort' : '4040',
}

shell_service = makeService(options)

application = Application('test')
serviceCollection = IServiceCollection(application)

shell_service.setServiceParent(serviceCollection)
```

The 'password file' `users.txt` may contain as little as one line with a sample username and password, e.g. `admin:admin`.

Start the test server:

```
host:server user$ twistd -noy test_manhole_2.tac
(omitting DeprecationWarnings about md5 and sha)
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] Log opened.
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] twistd 8.2.0 (/usr/bin/python2.6 2.6.1) starting up.
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor.
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory starting on 4040
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] Starting factory <twisted.internet.protocol.ServerFactory instance at 0x10181e710>
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] start service:  <twisted.application.service.MultiService instance at 0x1012553b0>
2011-08-24 17:44:26+1000 [-] start service:  <twisted.application.internet.TCPServer instance at 0x10181e998>
```

In a second shell, run a telnet client - note that some of this is actually guesswork as the buggy Mac OSX readline (or whatever else is the to blame) seems to swallow some shell output:

```
host:client user$ telnet localhost 4040
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Username: admin
Password: *****

>>> dir()
['__builtins__']
```

So now it seems I've gone from having a useless `service` object to no object at all.

How is twisted.manhole used correctly ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is the password "admin"?

Comment: yes. i keep using port 4040, username admin and password admin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep using `twisted.conch` and put something in the namespace dictionary.

```
namespace = {"your_application_object": some_object}

options = {
    # for some reason, these must
    # all exist, even if None
    'namespace'  : namespace,
    'passwd'     : 'users.txt',
    'sshPort'    : None,
    'telnetPort' : '4040',
}
```